# Python repository organization w.r.t. tests and PyDev

Tags: python, unit-testing, pydev

I'm trying to set up a Python repository for some code. I've read the [Structuring Your Project](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/) tutorial and set everything up as suggested. Concretely, I have the following directory structure:

```
repo_root/
   some_module.py
   tests/
       context.py
       test_some_module.py
```

The `context.py` file contains exactly what the tutorial suggests:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

import some_module
```

The `test_some_module.py` file imports `some_module` like so:

```
from context import some_module
```

instead of

```
from .context import some_module
```

as the site suggests.

I'm using PyDev and running the unit tests by right-clicking on the test file and selecting `Run As/unittest`. This causes the test to run in the `tests` directory, where `context` is visible and the import is successful. PyDev shows `Unresolved import`. I'm guessing this is because it runs the parser from the project root. If I add `tests` to the `PYTHONPATH` it still doesn't work. Only if I add an `__init__.py` file in `tests` does PyDev stop showing errors, because it's treating `tests` as a library.

What is the correct way to set up my repository? Are tests supposed to only be called in the `tests` directory or should they also be start-able from the repository root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyDev doesn't really work well if you don't have `__init__` files in the package (even if it's for tests), so, my suggestion is adding `__init__` there.